# Solving a 3D Poisson Equation with simple Neumann Boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

I have been wrestling with the following problem for several days to get an analytical solution. Any suggestions or guideline will be greatly appreciated. 
The PDE is being solved over a cube, $ -a\le x \le a$; $-b\le y \le b$; $0 \le z \le L; $

$ \nabla ^2 u=f(x,y) $

$ {\partial u \over \partial x}=0 $ $\;\;\;\;$at $ x=-a$ and $x=a$;

$ {\partial u \over \partial y}=0 $ $\;\;\;\;$at $ y=-b$ and $y=b$;

$ {\partial u \over \partial z}=Cx $ $\;$at $ z=0$ where $C$ is a constant;

$ {\partial u \over \partial z}=0 $ $\;\;\;\;$at $ z=L$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $\partial/\partial z$ of both sides to obtain

$$ \nabla^2u_z = 0 $$

Perform separation of variables by setting $u_z(x,y,z) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$ to get

$$ \frac{X''}{X} + \frac{Y''}{Y} = -\frac{Z''}{Z} = -\lambda^2 $$

The third boundary condition implies that the $X$ part must be odd and the $Y$ part must be even, so we have the following solution forms

$$ X_n = \sin\left[\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi x}{a}\right] $$

$$ Y_m = \cos\left( m\frac{\pi y}{b} \right) $$

$$ Z_{nm} = \frac{\sinh\left[\lambda_{nm}(L-z)\right]}{\sinh(\lambda_{nm} L)} $$

where

$$ \lambda_{nm}^2 = \left[\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{a}\right]^2 + \left( m\frac{\pi}{b} \right)^2  $$

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thanks. Could we let the Xn take the form of sinh(), Ym takes the form cos()?

Comment: The boundary conditions imply a periodic X and Y, therefore they have to be trig functions. This forces Z to be hyperbolic ($\sinh$ or $\cosh$), which we then narrow down to $\sinh$ since $\cosh$ is never zero. You're welcome to test all the cases though.

Comment: Thanks, Dylan. I tried different cases, and realized my boundary condition might not be right. You are absolutely right. I want to give the explicit f(x,y). I am new to the site. Should I edit the original question, or mark this as solved, and start a new one?

Comment: You're probably better off starting a new question since it's a different problem now. If you knew $f(x,y)$ explicitly there's another way to do it. Make sure to  pick the nest answer to close this one though,

Comment: To clarify, a smarter way to solve this problem is to split the function into a particular solution plus a homogeneous part $u = u_p + u_h$, where $\nabla^2 u_p = f(x,y)$ and $\nabla^2 u_h = 0$

Comment: Thanks. I will try as you suggested.